# Brightcove two players API

Tags: javascript, brightcove

I'm using the brightcove api as the guide shows (below), but my problem is that I can't manage two players this way, and I need it:

```
<object id="VideoBrightcove?c=4&m=2&s=2" class="BrightcoveExperience">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="480" />
  <param name="height" value="270" />
  <param name="playerID" value="2549948545001" />
  <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAABmA9XpXk~,-Kp7jNgisreVadKjzdyJfLcfukyXcGqB" />
  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
  <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
  <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
  <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="BCLS.onTemplateLoad" />
  <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="BCLS.onTemplateReady">
  <param name="@videoPlayer" value="1754261637001" />
</object>

<script>
    var BCLS = (function() {
        var player,APIModules,mediaEvent,videoPlayer;
        return {
            onTemplateLoad : function (experienceID) { 
                //do something
            },
            onTemplateReady : function (evt) { 
                //do something
            },
            onProgress : function (evt) {
                //do something
            },
            onBegin : function (evt) {
                //do something
            },
            onComplete : function (evt) {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }());
</script>
```

Any idea to manage more than one player?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the code samples you'll for using the Smart Player API use global variables, or as I assume you're doing, `BCLS.player` for the "experience", `BCLS.videoPlayer` for the video player module and so on. That won't work well with multiple players unless you maintain a separate set of load/ready handler functions and a separate set of variables for each player. That won't scale well.

The easiest way to work with multiple players is to rely on the event passed to the event handler as this includes the player id at `event.target.experience.id`.

```
function onTemplateReady(event) {
  var player = brightcove.api.getExperience(event.target.experience.id);
  var videoPlayer = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
}
```

When using addEventHandler, you'll need to wrap functions in an anonymous function instead of using just the function name:

```
videoPlayer.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.PLAY, function(event) {onPlay(event)})
//instead of videoPlayer.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.PLAY, onPlay})
```

You could pass other modules etc to those functions if you need to, e.g. if this were done in the `onTemplateReady` above, the `player` can be available in the player handler:

```
videoPlayer.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.PLAY, function(event) {onPlay(event,player)})
```

See [this example](http://solutions.brightcove.com/cs/smart-player-api/multiple-players.html) which uses some of the above techniques, which is an example of stopping other players when one plays.